# Any way to recover a file with bad blocks (CRC error in Windows)?

Tags: ntfs, data-recovery, hard-drive-recovery, bad-blocks, crc

What I see is this:

- Windows complains when reading a file because the CRC for it mis-matches its calculated CRC.
- This means NTFS has a CRC for the file.
- I expect the offending block/sector can be known, or at least guessed.
- I also expect that "wrong data" can be read from the disk.
- If the bits of "wrong data" were inverted one by one, by brute force we could find the correct data.
- A file could thus be recovered using statistics and brute-forcing bits to match the CRC.

My question is, does any software do this kind of thing? Any way I could do it (I'd be happy enough to get the CRC, the drive's "wrong" data, know which is the offending block/sector there, and write a script to brute it myself, if relevant directions are given).

By the way, this is a mechanical HDD.

**Edit:** After taking a look with hex editors and such, I noticed that a bad block appears as garbage, such as filled with zeros or a copy of the last block (this seems to depend on the program), so in order to get the "real data" that is corrupted, we'd have to disable some hardware-correction that refuses to read a block which is bad. I believe this is called ECC.
Also, I expect that if just a few bits are marking a block as "bad", then some 32-bit checksum from Windows could be used to brute force a match.

So this question may be answered simply with guidance to do this by myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, what I wanted to do [is not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9686742/124119) (NTFS does not store a CRC, the hard drive does).

However, I recommend SpinRite, as it is in the process of recovering a hard drive (with a painfully slow speed of some GBs per day, occasionaly I mount the filesystem to see how's the state of the files).

It may or may not work for you, so if the data is worth a few thousand dollars, go to a specialized hard drive recovery place. It's terribly costly but sometimes experts get data out of unlikely situations.

Oh, and one last recommendation: if the data is worth a few thousands, DON'T touch the drive. Don't mount it anymore, don't dare to boot from it, don't run `chkdsk`, don't do ANYTHING. It might compromise the drive's chance to being recovered.
But if it's a drive with songs, movies, or other non-im**por**ta**n**t content, don't miss the chance to play with it to your heart's content! :)

Comment: I remember using SpinRite back in 1995 :-) Nowadays `ddrescue` might be a better way (can get it via Cygwin).