# Best copy process with pending sectors?

Tags: ntfs, data-recovery, hard-drive-recovery, bad-sectors, bad-blocks

I'm a bit confused due to this thread: [Any way to recover a file with bad blocks (CRC error in Windows)?](https://superuser.com/questions/399150/any-way-to-recover-a-file-with-bad-blocks-crc-error-in-windows?rq=1)

I recently decided on a Synology DS1815+ with four WD4000FYYZ HDDs (SHR2, which is Synology’s RAID6).

Up to now my data (primarily music) was only stored on a Windows machine with internal Western Digital HDDs (Green) without any RAID. Some of the old hard drives have some (C5) Current Pending Sectors.

Is the data damaged on such sectors or how do I have to understand that values?

How can I make sure that no damaged files are transferred to the new Synology NAS?

I'd like to run a tool that scans the old hard drives and outputs a log file that informs if some files have problems, like

> "abc.mp3, XYZ.jpg" is located on a bad sector or cannot be read.

What happens if I copy the data over the network just using Windows via copy-n-paste and Windows attains such a bad sector, which cannot be read?

I already get replies from other german forums that there is absolutely no problem (with a low number of pending sectors) and that Windows never copies defective data and would bring an error message. So can I assume that all data are in perfect order when windows brings no error message?

If somebody could confirm that again, I would definitely start with the copy process.

Comment: Can't really see your problem. Copying the data from faulty HDD to good HDD is non-infectious, unless there's any sort of malware. But any HDD issue that's hardware in nature just slows down operations and may render affected data corrupted/unreadable. But it will not damage anything...
Windows on encountering bad sector will try to recover it, so copy process, especially over network, will be slow and may require manual input.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks!

we use the files for live audio/video shows and just want to exclude breakdowns due to defective data.

However, everything seems to be OK, if Windows never copies defective data or shows an error message if there is something wrong.

Comment: It isn't clear what this post is, except it isn't an answer.  Answers are intended to be a definitive solution to the problem.  If this is just clarifying information, it should be added to your question or posted in a comment.  This will encourage answers.  If this is intended to indicate that there is no longer an issue and you want to post an answer, create an answer that will inform readers how or why the question is resolved (could be an explanation that addresses your original uncertainties).  Then people will know the problem is solved (and will benefit from what you learned).